# LED circuit with 17 parallel diodes

Tags: led

I have a parallel LED circuit with with 17 red LEDs. I am using a 555 and microcontroller with a 9V alkaline battery (500mAh).

In chasing mode, 3 red LEDs go continuously from right to left, so 3x20mAh is 60mAh, 500mah / 60mah is 8.5 hours battery use time.

That is in my situation correct, after 8.5 hours you see dramatically that the LEDs are less bright.

Playing with my circuit and taking the microcontroller out and put the pins some lower, (so some pins stays outside) 2 LEDs were continuously lighting without chasing, just sitting on 1 place, so 2 diodes 2x20mah is 40mah, 500mah / 40mah is 12.5 hours.

I put a new alkaline battery inside, I let it burn and I frequently checked it, what normally must be 12 to 12,5 hours it burned at same strong 15,5 hours long, just at the 16 hours burning time it dramatically increased in power with same effect as the chasing mode.

Does anyone knows what is happenning? If yes, is there a remedy besides using aa batteries in series to make it in chasing mode with the alkaline 9V battery same as the 2 LEDs what continuously burning for longer the time as the calculation laws describes?

Comment: 16 hours burning time he dramaticly increased,sorry increase is decrease, my english sorry again

Comment: If you're using a microcontroller then what's the use of a 555? It can't do anything the microcontroller can't do better.

Comment: sorry, i use it for 3 differend cind of chasing.

Comment: what kinds? A microcontroller can't do just 3 kinds of chasing, but for all practical purposes an unlimited number of chasing modes. Like I said, I can't think of a problem which you can solve with a 555 which a microcontroller can't.

Comment: You missunderstand me, i not have a problem, i also not want start discussion what can and what not can,with respect,just asking what reason makes that 1 sort have exact duration of calculation and the other not,Dave said that the actual current draw is not what i think it is,,that is a possibility,and i keep thet open, thank you

Comment: I can't quite make out what the problem is here - is it that the battery is not lasting as long as you expect it to? Could you show us a schematic please?

Answer (score 0):

Battery capacity is not really a constant, it varies significantly with the average current being drawn, so a larger apparent capacity at reduced current is not all that surprising.

Other than that, it's hard to understand what you're asking. Perhaps you could give us a detailed schematic diagram of your setup. You use the phrase "no series" which is a hint that you might have no series resistors on your LEDs. If that's the case, the actual current draw might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Hello Dave, i will post a youtube film to explain, seeing explains better then words, i understand what you try to say, i have frequenz to turn higher or lower, the circuit stay same, the diodes light up same as i not touch the frequenze, if chasing mode is correct, then the rest must be also correct measurments, 1 diode or 2 or 3, it will stay same, but after i post on youtube today or tommorow you will see the board and lightning from both sides as i above wrote, Thank you Tobey Jaffey for correcting my english for the people understand better.